# MS Graph Powershell SDK - Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'BodyParameter'

Tags: json, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm currently trying to create a security baseline that can be deployed through the MS Graph Powershell SDK. However I'm having troubles inputting the body of my request.

The request is in a separate JSON file to the script and looks like this:

```
{
   "description": "Basic Security Configuration recommended by company.",
   "displayName": "Company Security Baseline",
   "value": [
       {
           "definitionId": "deviceConfiguration--windows10EndpointProtectionConfiguration_defenderOfficeMacroCodeAllowWin32ImportsType",
           "valueJson": "\"warn\"",
           "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.deviceManagementStringSettingInstance",
           "value": "warn"
       }
   ]
}
```

I then grab the content from this file as follows and input it into the New-MgDeviceManagementTemplateInstance command.

```
# Create request from JSON file.
$request = Get-Content SecurityBaseline.json 

# Create new template instance.
$instance = New-MgDeviceManagementTemplateInstance -DeviceManagementTemplateId $templateId -BodyParameter $request
```

After which I receive this error:

```
New-MgDeviceManagementTemplateInstance : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'BodyParameter'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type
"Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.IPaths1Acen0GDevicemanagementTemplatesDevicemanagementtemplateIdMicrosoftGraphCreateinstancePostRequestbodyContentApplicationJsonSchema".
At line:1 char:112
+ ...  -DeviceManagementTemplateId "$($templateId)" -BodyParameter $request
+                                                                  ~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-MgDeviceManagementTemplateInstance], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,New-MgDeviceManagementTemplateInstance
```

Any assistance on what format I need to input this data as would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the beta SDK itself. Since this is  beta cmdlet its probably still under change, you can try to run a raw http request using PowerShell and see if you get a 200.

Comment: You can open an issue on GitHub: [msgraph-sdk-powershell](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if it was an issue with the beta SDK or if its working as intended but this seems to work for the moment.

```
$instance = New-MgDeviceManagementTemplateInstance -DeviceManagementTemplateId $templateId -BodyParameter "$request"
```